# RandomAccessFile.seek() not working on Linux

Tags: java, linux, io, randomaccessfile

I am using some sort of tail -f implementation to tail a file for changes (pretty much like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160510001134/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=226) ). For this I am using a RandomAccessFile, periodically check if the file length has increased and if so, seek and read the new lines (everything happening in a separate thread of the FileTailer).

Now, everything is working as expected on Windows, but I tested my program on Linux and it does not work as expected. Here is the run()-method of the FileTailer class. Specifically where it fails on linux is the part where file.seek(filePointer) gets called and then file.readLine(), of which the latter surprisingly returns NULL (although the filePointer gets incremented correctly if I append content to the file getting tailed at runtime).

```
public void run() {
// The file pointer keeps track of where we are in the file
long filePointer = 0;

// Determine start point
if(startAtBeginning){
  filePointer = 0;
}
else {
  filePointer = logfile.length();
}

try {
  // Start tailing
  tailing = true;
  RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(logfile, "r");
  while(tailing) {
      // Compare the length of the file to the file pointer
      long fileLength = logfile.length();
      System.out.println("filePointer = " + filePointer + " | fileLength = " + fileLength);
      if(fileLength < filePointer) {
        // Log file must have been rotated or deleted; 
        // reopen the file and reset the file pointer
        file = new RandomAccessFile(logfile, "r");
        filePointer = 0;
      }

      if(fileLength > filePointer) {
        // There is data to read
        file.seek(filePointer);
        String line = file.readLine();
        System.out.println("new line = " + line);
        while(line != null){
          if(!line.isEmpty())
            try {
                fireNewFileLine(line);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          line = file.readLine();
        }
        filePointer = file.getFilePointer();
      }
      // Sleep for the specified interval
      sleep(sampleInterval);

  }

  // Close the file that we are tailing
  file.close();
}
catch(InterruptedException | IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Like I said, everything is working as it should on Windows, but on Linux the String variable "line" is NULL after it should have been filled with the newly appended line, so fireNewLine gets called on NULL and everything goes to crap.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens on Linux Systems?

Comment: There's no evidence here that `seek()` is the problem, but I don't know why you're calling `seek()` at all. You don't need to. You should always be positioned at the end of the file. Nothing is going to change your position in the file except your own `readLine()` calls.

Comment: And in fact you don't need `RandomAccessFile`at all. Use a `BufferedReader`, and just sleep while `readLine()` is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this, or `RandomAccessFile`. You are always at the end of the file. All you need is this:

```
public void run() {

    try {
      // Start tailing
      tailing = true;
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logfile));
      String line;
      while (tailing) {
          while ((line = reader.readLine() != null) {
              System.out.println("new line = " + line);
              if(!line.isEmpty()) {
                  try {
                      fireNewFileLine(line);
                  } catch (ParseException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }
          // Sleep for the specified interval
          sleep(sampleInterval);
        }
        // Close the file that we are tailing
        reader.close();
    } catch(InterruptedException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with maybe some provision for reopening the file.

E&OE